# i want to replace these textbox with place holder text in textbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my project is having the below code for textbox i want to replace these textbox with place holder text in textbox in wpf.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="1000" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
             Grid.Row="1"        
             Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="100"  
                     Text="{Binding QuestionText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is either extend the TextBox control on your own or use what worked for me:

[Watermark TextBox](http://watermarktextbox.codeplex.com/documentation)

read the instructions at the link and implement accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get the language but hopefully you wanted to bind it this way

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="1000" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
             Grid.Row="1"        
             Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="100"                          
PlaceholderText="{Binding QuestionText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Comment: In my project i developed all textboxes in the above manner but now i want to replace all textboxes with place holder text (water mark type textboxes) in wpf..

Comment: Then replace ur Text property with PlaceholderText as shown in code.